# `glog` example is not showing output as expected

Tags: c++, glog

I am trying to understand [glog](https://github.com/google/glog) and therefore trying to run the example code on their github page.

I have installed `glog` (version - 0.6.0) and its dependency `gflags` (version - 2.2) on my mac OS (10.15.7)

I compile the example below

```
#include <glog/logging.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Initialize Google’s logging library.
    google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);

    // test with setting a value for num_cookies
    int num_cookies = 3;

    // ...
    LOG(INFO) << "Found " << num_cookies << " cookies";
}
```

using the following command (and it compiles without any errors or warnings).

```
g++ glog-test.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lglog -lgflags -o glog-test.o
```

When I run the example using the following command,

```
./glog-test.o --logtostderr=1 --stderrthreshold=0
```

I expect to see the message `Found 3 cookies` on my terminal, but I see nothing being printed.

I have also experimented with different values for `logtostderr` (0, 1) and `stderrthreshold` (0, 1, 2, 3) and nothing gets written to the directory or gets printed on the terminal.

Any help in understanding what I am doing wrong here would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the command line flags manually through `gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags`

```cpp
#include <glog/logging.h>
#incldue <gflags/gflags.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Initialize Google’s logging library.
    google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);

    gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);

    // test with setting a value for num_cookies
    int num_cookies = 3;

    // ...
    LOG(INFO) << "Found " << num_cookies << " cookies";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just checked, the following works..

```
GLOG_stderrthreshold=0 GLOG_logtostderr=1 ./glog-test.o
```

which gives

```
Found 3 cookies
```

I do have `gflags` and installed, as seen by

```
cd /usr/local/lib 
ls -l | grep "libgflags"
```

which gives

```
   -lrwxr-xr-x    1 sn  admin        48 Jun  5  2020 libgflags.2.2.2.dylib -> ../Cellar/gflags/2.2.2/lib/libgflags.2.2.2.dylib
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 sn  admin        46 Jun  5  2020 libgflags.2.2.dylib -> ../Cellar/gflags/2.2.2/lib/libgflags.2.2.dylib
    -rw-r--r--    1 sn  admin    170520 Jun 27 00:35 libgflags.a
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 sn  admin        42 Jun  5  2020 libgflags.dylib -> ../Cellar/gflags/2.2.2/lib/libgflags.dylib
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 sn  admin        58 Jun  5  2020 libgflags_nothreads.2.2.2.dylib -> ../Cellar/gflags/2.2.2/lib/libgflags_nothreads.2.2.2.dylib
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 sn  admin        56 Jun  5  2020 libgflags_nothreads.2.2.dylib -> ../Cellar/gflags/2.2.2/lib/libgflags_nothreads.2.2.dylib
    -rw-r--r--    1 sn  admin    168096 Jun 27 00:35 libgflags_nothreads.a
    lrwxr-xr-x    1 sn  admin        52 Jun  5  2020 libgflags_nothreads.dylib -> ../Cellar/gflags/2.2.2/lib/libgflags_nothreads.dylib
```

so I am not sure why

```
./glog-test.o --logtostderr=1 --stderrthreshold=0
```

didn't work.